How do I run this model in HuggingFace from Nvidia and Mistral?
The model is:

nvidia/Mistral-NeMo-12B-Instruct

And the link in HuggingFace nvidia/Mistral-NeMo-12B-Instruct
Most model pages in HuggingFace have example Python code.
But this model page doesn't have any example code.
How do I run this model in Python?
This is example code for some model:
# Use a pipeline as a high-level helper
from transformers import pipeline

messages = [
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who are you?"},
]
pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model="mistralai/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407")
pipe(messages)

